# Referring a source pydev project to another pydev project fails in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7

How to give reference from one source pydev project to another destination pydev project. I tried to remove the .pyc files from the referring project, it also fails. Later i tried after giving the reference i restarted the eclipse, this also fails.

Can any one solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep unique names for root packages in both referred and referring projects. Dont keep same package names for root packages, then it works properly.